# LVM partition mounts only for root

Tags: permissions, lvm

I have created LVM partition in `myvol` and file system on it:

```
sudo lvcreate -L 10G myvol -n part1
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/myvol-part1
```

New partition appeared in file manager, but when I open it I can't create and delete files without root privileges. I tried to remount it with different commands but all in all it was accessible only for root. How can I mount it for user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the mount folders permission, so that other users are able to access it.

```
chown -R user:group <folder name>
```

P.S Mount the folder onto the partition before running chown.

Comment: It looks like workaroud. F.e. external media auto mounts and I can access data on it without using `chown`. I want the same behavior from my partition

Comment: Add the mount in your `/etc/fstab` and it will automount the partition on boot.

Comment: Sorry for misspell. I do not want my partition to automount but I want it be accessible for me without `sudo` when I mount it, like external media. When I insert usb drive and open it in file manager I can edit all files from the start with no `chown`

Comment: You are able to see the content of external media because the permission's on the mount folders and the files in the media are readable and writable. When you mount using root, you can have your media readble and writble if your content and the folder have the right permission's.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will use `chown`